# How do I fix "Error: Illegal range in part select"?

Tags: system-verilog

```
bit[2:0]  size;
bit[2:0]  num;
bit[59:0] data;
data = 60'h12345;
num = 3'h1;
size = 3'h1;

data = {(num+1){data[(size+1)*10-1:0]}};
```

> ////Error-[IRIPS] Illegal range in part select

> ////Warning-[WUIMCM] Unknown in multiconcat multiplier

How do I fix these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SystemVerilog does not allow variable widths in operands. You need to create a mask to select the part of the `data` variable, and need to use a `for` loop for replication.

```
bit [59:0] data_select = data;

data_select &= (61'b1 << (size+1)*10) - 1;
for(int i=0;i<num+1;i++) begin
   data <<= (size+1)*10;
   data |= data_select;
end
```